# Vue.js dynamic add and remove

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm learning Vue.js for my game and I was wondering if there is a way to dynamically add and remove components in Vue.js ?
Here's my current code

```
var vue = new Vue({
    el: "#fui",
    template: ``
})

const HelloCtor = Vue.extend({
  props: ['text'],
  template: '<div class="hello">{{ text }}</div>',
});

const vm = new HelloCtor({
  data: {
    text: 'HI :)'
  }
});

/*
How can I do something like this?

vue.add(vm);
vue.remove(vm);

*/
```

The code basically speaks for himself

So, is it possible (and how?) to dynamically add and remove Vue.js components to a Vue?

Comment: What your code speaks is not possible to implement. But if you can explain further the business requirement of yours , I am sure there is a way out.

Comment: @charith I have a game where you have multiple items like alert boxes, inventory, settings ect... They are draggable & can be closed. I need to be able to dynamically remove them and add them

Comment: Are you sure you dont just want [conditional rendering](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html)?

Comment: @BertEvans Well, for alerts for example I want to completly remove the component from memory / DOM when it's closed

Comment: If you use `v-if` the component is completely removed from the DOM.

Comment: @BertEvans and it isn't possible to do like in my code? I found this really easier and more structurated for what I want to do

Comment: @JeePing Vue is a data driven framework where what's displayed is a reflection of state. Your approach is imperative. If you want to do it your way you will be fighting the framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a place to put `vm` in the template. Then you can `$mount` the component manually to an element with `vm.$mount('el')`. You can also delete the element with `vm.$destroy(true)`. Destroy won't delete the element from the DOM. You'll need to do that manually with something like `(vm.$el).remove()`

I'm not 100% this is what you're looking for, and when you find yourself manually calling `$destroy()` you are probably not doing things right…but it does let you take control of the creating and destruction of components.

Something like this will let you create then destroy your component (note in this case once you destroy vm it's gone):

```
<div id="fui">
    <button @click="make">Make</button>
    <button  @click="bye">destroy</button>
    <div id="mountme"></div>
</div>

<script>

    const HelloCtor = Vue.extend({
        props: ['text'],
        template: '<div class="hello">This has been {{ text }}</div>',

    })

    const vm = new HelloCtor ({
        data: {
            text: "Mounted"
        }
    })

    var vue = new Vue({
        el: "#fui",
        template: ``,
        methods: {
            make: () => {
                vm.$mount('#mountme')
            },
            bye: () => {
                vm.$destroy(true); 
                (vm.$el).remove();}
            }

        })


</script>
```

Comment: Sounds OK... Unless the fact that you get an error after clicking Make & Destroy and then Make https://jsfiddle.net/2pkesc47/ http://prntscr.com/fl7itn

Comment: That's why I wrote '(note in this case once you destroy vm it's gone)'. If you want to add it again you need to write code that creates the new component again. I left it out so would would see that destroy does in fact destroy your component.